# What does GA means in "when Winter 16 is GA"?

Tags: package, org, lightning

In order to be Lightning Ready, doc says :

> Alternatively, partners can deploy unmanaged code to a Partner
>   Pre-Release org and package the changes when Winter 16 is GA

First, what does `GA` mean ?

Then, can I create an unmanaged package from my developer environment and install it in a Pre-Release org ?

Finally, what's the special caracteristics for a Pre-Release org comparing to a Developer org ?

Comment: The answers below are correct, but since the Winter '16 release is now Generally Available and released to all production orgs, whatever doc you're reading that contains this advice probably doesn't apply in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before understanding the GA you should understand the Pre-release orgs.

**Pre release orgs:**

Salesforce typically has 3 major releases a year

- Winter
- Spring
- Summer

So before major release happen to end customers Salesforce create some pre-release orgs where these releases available so that partners who has their app in app exchange can test their app by conducting regression testing on pre-release org to ensure a seamless upgrade. same thing available for Developers as well where they can register for Pre-release and test their code with this new release.

**GA mean**

GA stands for **Generally available** it means any feature which is released to 
end user marked as GA.

You may also see **BETA** against some functionality it may require some manual intervention from system administrator prior to use that functionality by activating that feature in your org.

I assume that you will get all answers now. Let us know if you still have any question.

Answer (score 1):

GA means generally available.

Yes you can, an easy way to do it would be looking at [Salesforce deploy button.](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/09/27/the-new-github-deploy-to-salesforce-tool-button/)

Orgs are generally differentiated between Sandbox and Production. In production, you <strike>can't</strike> should not directly modify Apex code. The differences between pre-release and development org are solely defined by your organisational procedures.